# Configuring PTR records!

Tags: ptr-record

One of our client requires PTR records to be configured. Their ISP does not support the same. Can I create a PTR record on my name servers for an IP owned by a different ISP?

Comment: I don't know of any business-grade ISPs that doesn't offer some form of control over PTR records; typically through some sort of web interface. I live in the UK, though, perhaps it's a different story elsewhere. (If indeed you are elsewhere...)

Answer (score 5):

You can create all the PTR records you want on your DNS servers but nobody else in the world is going to ever "see" them if your DNS servers aren't authoritative for the namespace the PTRs fall within.

You're going to need the cooperation of the owner of authoritative DNS servers for the IP range you want to create PTR records for. They can either create the PTR records for you or delegate them to you.

BTW, they *can* delegate individual PTR records to you (see http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/avoid-rfc-2317-delegation-example-1.html for examples) in lieu of delegating an entire /24 of PTRs to you. They may not know they can do this, but it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

PTR records need to be created on the authoritative DNS server for whatever netblock the IPs are in. So unless your ISP delegates a netblock to you, you will not be able to create PTR records.