# Getting no servers could be reached when using host, nslookup and dig

Tags: domain, command-line-interface, dns-zone

I'm following this answer [How do I get the mx records for a domain from *nix command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/44178/how-do-i-get-the-mx-records-for-a-domain-from-nix-command-line/44267#44267?newreg=f0546691d7ad43da8ce8ed3dd4b8763e) but every time I get an error:

> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwXQM.png)

Can anyone help to sort out this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting that information may be blocked for security reasons.

Comment: @Davidw I don't think so... if you are using any online tools like https://dnschecker.org/ it'll show all the information.

Answer (score 5):

That message occurs when dig/host/nslookup cannot get a response from the DNS servers configured for the system ( whatever is in /etc/resolv.conf).  Basically: DNS isn't working at all on singhal right now.

You might (very dependent on a lot of local network considerations) be able to get a result from Google's own DNS servers, e.g.:

dig -t MX google.com @8.8.8.8

Comment: thanks... it works but in this case where I'm found the IP address like 8.8.8.8

Comment: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are Google's well-known public DNS servers, as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS

Comment: lolz... if you know this IP or you can find out from other sources like Wikipedia then what's the purpose of this tool?

Comment: I don't think you understand what's going on here.  Your local DNS setup isn't working; I pointed you at a public recursive DNS server that you could use to see if the issue was local networking issues (e.g.your computer can't talk to *any* DNS server at all) or if it was local to your network.  It looks like the latter.

Comment: lol... well then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after setting up a mail server on a VPS.  I first noticed it after an email hard bounced with

> Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname, [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]: retry timeout exceeded

I checked with `host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` on my server's IP address and got the same reply as OP :

> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Same with `nslookup XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` :

> ** server can't find XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.in-addr.arpa: SERVFAIL

I couldn't find much information on how to set it up, everything seemed find on the server side, so I asked my VPS provider, and they acknowledged that it had to be done on their side, which they did.  It took about a day for the changes to be propagated, the next day `host` and `nslookup` found the reverse DNS / PTR.

So **tl;dr** : fixing this issue is probably the job of your VPS provider.

Comment: Related : https://serverfault.com/questions/208199/configuring-ptr-records https://serverfault.com/questions/344665/adding-ptr-to-dns https://serverfault.com/questions/654462/450-4-7-1-client-host-rejected-cannot-find-your-hostname